# use services in Angular 4 router

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular4-router

Here is my route.

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [dbs.ConfigGuard]},
    {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

I want to generate *`path names`* dynamically.

Like `{path : xyzService.getKey('login'), component: LoginComponent}`

So, my question is, How can I inject my `xyzService` here to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

This seems not possible to me since , you can not inject service in module in angular .In modules you only provide the service and are then being injected in components and used here .

Moreover why do you want to create the route path dynamically .

What is your use case ?

Comment: I have a large application, which is entirely configurable to render the page.

When we are using the multilanguage feature, the router links also changed, I know it might be bad design but until we changed the core of the application, we want it to be worked for now.

my service has a resource map, which can get the value of keys, I'm searching for a way by which I can construct my routers.

Answer (score 0):

Coincidently, I *just* read a Github issue relating to this on the Angular project's repo: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23486

I don't think dynamic routes are currently supported by the Angular Router, but that issue (which, as of this posting, hasn't been officially responded to yet) should address your question.

As someone points out in that issue, you'll probably need to accomplish dynamic routing outside of the Angular Router. I.e. you could add a wildcard route that leads to a component which manually reads the URL and builds the appropriate view. Basically, build  your own router.

If you want your whole application to feature dynamic routing, I think you may need to use a different router than the official Angular Router.